# How to expand datalist items on keyup event

Tags: jquery, html-datalist

i will get some data list items on `keyup` even .

what i want is  show those `datalist items automatically` on key up

```
<div class="col-md-3 "> 
                <input type="text" class="form-control" list="items"  id="proname" placeholder="Product Name" style="margin-left: 12px;"> 
                    <datalist id="items">
                      // data comes here dynamically on keyup
                     </datalist>
</div>
```

i tried to trigger `doubleclick` event on keyup of the datalist input box .so that datalist items will get expanded

```
$('#proname').keyup(function(){
             //code to get dynamic data into datalist
                      $(this).trigger( "dbclick" );
     });
```

please help me out , i want to expand datalist automatically.

Comment: 1.`$(this).trigger( "dbclick" );`need to be`$("#items").trigger( "dbclick" );`2. `keyup` need to be `focusout` (otherwise on each key press `dbclick` will run and system will not respond properly).3.Make sure that you have dbclick handler already defined.

Comment: no even if its focusout browser is not responding

Comment: cant we expand without dbclick

Comment: what do you mean by expanding here?

Comment: showing datalist items

Comment: so initially it's hidden ? complete  `<datalist id="items"> element`?

Comment: no its not hidden data list items comes dynamically on key up ,they will be shown up when we type something into inputbox

Comment: it is similar to select